# How to take value of a variable in Gatling script

Tags: gatling

I have extracted token value from the login api call.but i am not able to use that variable value into next api call.My code is given below

```
 val scn = scenario("test login")
  .exec(http("login call")
  .post("https://api.k6.io/v3/account/login")
  .headers(headers_1)
  .body(RawFileBody("data/login.json"))
  .check(status.is(200))
  .check(jsonPath("$.token.key").saveAs("tokenId")))
  .pause(21)
  .exec(http("edit profile call")
  .post("https://api.k6.io/v3/users/3187878")
  .headers(headers_1)
  .header("Authorization", "Token ${tokenId}")
  .body(RawFileBody("data/editprofile.json"))
  .check(status.is(200)))
```

but the call get failed. I am not getting the value of that variable in the second call.

`{"key":"4c713e3f5d362f0002f6eef737401e249c154bed"}`

i need to use the value of 'key' in the header for next api call as in the format of

```
.header("Authorization", "Token 4c713e3f5d362f0002f6eef737401e249c154bed")
```

but it is not getting in this format.where i am going wrong?Can anyone help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your way of capturing data with a check and re-injecting it with Gatling Expression Language is correct.

Possible reasons your scenario doesn't work:

- the "login call" request fails and is not able to capture the data
- you use RawFileBody but maybe some data in there needs to be dynamic, just like your Authorization header

If you want to check what's been captured, you can add an extra action before your pause:

```scala
.exec { session =>
  println(session("tokenId").as[String])
  session
}
```